# tic tac toe in jquery can i get this code shorter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if it possible to make this code shorter in section where function checks if someone won the game

i have tried using case break, but i have no idea how makee it work in this example

```
<script>
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                  if ($("#item1").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item2").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item3").hasClass(".winnerX")) {
                    $(".win").text("Player X won");
        } else if ($("#item4").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item5").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item6").hasClass(".winnerX")) {
          $(".win").text("Player X won");
        } else if ($("#item7").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item8").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item9").hasClass(".winnerX")) {
          $(".win").text("Player X won");
        } else if ($("#item1").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item4").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item7").hasClass(".winnerX")) {
          $(".win").text("Player X won");
        } else if ($("#item2").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item5").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item8").hasClass(".winnerX")) {
          $(".win").text("Player X won");
        } else if ($("#item3").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item6").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item9").hasClass(".winnerX")) {
          $(".win").text("Player X won");
        } else if ($("#item3").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item5").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item7").hasClass(".winnerX")) {
          $(".win").text("Player X won");
        } else if ($("#item1").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item5").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item9").hasClass(".winnerX")) {
          $(".win").text("Player X won");
        } else if ($("#item3").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item5").hasClass(".winnerX") && $("#item7").hasClass(".winnerX")) {
          $(".win").text("Player X won");
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($("#item1").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item2").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item3").hasClass(".winnerO")) {
          $(".win").text("Player O won");
        } else if ($("#item4").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item5").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item6").hasClass(".winnerO")) {
          $(".win").text("Player O won");
        } else if ($("#item7").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item8").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item9").hasClass(".winnerO")) {
          $(".win").text("Player O won");
        } else if ($("#item1").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item4").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item7").hasClass(".winnerO")) {
          $(".win").text("Player O won");
        } else if ($("#item2").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item5").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item8").hasClass(".winnerO")) {
          $(".win").text("Player O won");
        } else if ($("#item3").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item6").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item9").hasClass(".winnerO")) {
          $(".win").text("Player O won");
        } else if ($("#item3").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item5").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item7").hasClass(".winnerO")) {
          $(".win").text("Player O won");
        } else if ($("#item1").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item5").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item9").hasClass(".winnerO")) {
          $(".win").text("Player O won");
        } else if ($("#item3").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item5").hasClass(".winnerO") && $("#item7").hasClass(".winnerO")) {
          $(".win").text("Player O won");
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
            });
</script>
```

beside that everything works fine
link to full github https://gist.github.com/Sztrum/3061ceb6b1981c630e9d578f888fbbfb

Comment: Checking for 3,5 and 7 is in there twice.

Comment: Yeah you are right i didnt saw that ealier but i want short that even more

Comment: If your code works, then you might like to try at  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There's a number of changes I'd make.  First, have a function that returns true/false on a win for X and then only have "Player X won" code once.  This could be extended to return who won X/O/no-one yet.  I'd also convert the all `$(#).hasClass` calls into an array so they're only called once. Then you can combine a number of clauses, eg if (#1 && ((#2 && #3) || (#5 && #9) || (#4 && #7)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go with this approach

```js
winnerCombs = [
 [1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9],
 [1,4,7],
 [2,5,8],
 [3,6,9],
 [3,5,7],
 [1,5,9]
]

const checkWinner = player => {
  return winnerCombs.some(comb => comb.every(c => $("#item" + c).hasClass(player) ))
}
isWinnerX = checkWinner(".winnerX") // return true if winner is Player X
isWinnerY = checkWinner(".winnerY") // return true if winner is Player Y
```